# Best way to add sub module ignored content

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

I'm using a repository (B) as a submodule of my project (A). In that repo (B), there is an ingored directory, dedicated to local config files for that project.

I'd like to version the content of that directory from my own project (A). Since those files are gitignored from (B), I thought I could simply git-add them but I get `fatal: Pathspec 'oh-my-zsh/custom' is in submodule 'oh-my-zsh'`.

What is the best way to do that (I'd rather not change anyting in (B))?

Comment: Could you add what happens if you try to do this from a bash shell (instead your zsh shell)?

Comment: Exaclty the same thing. Why did you expect something different?

Comment: Sorry, brainfart. Didn't realize project (A) was *oh-my-zsh*, thought it was an error of some library provided by *oh-my-zsh*.  Guess I need more coffee.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using a symlink to the local files:

```
a
├── b
│   └── local -> ../b-local
└── b-local
```

This nicely separates content of repo *a* from that of repo *b*.   Furthermore, as `b/local` is *gitignored*, it should not be very intrusive to your current workflow.

Alternatively, [git subtree](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v1/Git-Tools-Subtree-Merging) might be worth a look.  It would let you import repo (B) as a subdirectory into repo (A).  Users of your repo would just have to clone a single repo and wouldn't have to go through the pesky <kbd>git submodule update --init</kbd> step.  The history of project (B) could be either squashed or kept completely as is.

Comment: The drawbak being that the symlink must be manually created after a git-clone.

Comment: Right.  Might be worth including a `setup` make task which initializes the submodules and sets the symlink (admittedly only a simple, not an elegant solution).

Comment: @gregseth Just remembered <kbd>git subtree</kbd> as an alternative for problems like these, added to the answer.

Comment: Wow, thanks, I think for me subtrees are the way to go. I found this guide to get started: https://medium.com/@porteneuve/mastering-git-subtrees-943d29a798ec