# Git submodule with unique local file in the submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I added a Git submodule.

```
git submodule add https://github.com/mrclay/minify.git my/path/minify
```

On my local file system, I then modify `my/path/minify/min/config.php` for my specific needs.

How do I prevent it from being overridden if I ever update the module?

How do I push the unique file from a local git filesystem to my remote git repository server, and pull it to another local git repository?

Comment: By "update the module" you mean pulling remote changes right?

Comment: Why the down vote?  I really need an answer.  Maybe Git can't be used this way and I shouldn't use a submodule?

Comment: It's not a duplicate, but [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/31315655/2425163) is similar enough that you might find it helpful.

Comment: @tarleb  Thanks. Symlink seems difficult to support, and I concluded that best not to try to use a submodule.